# Detect remote desktop

Tags: remote, vnc

Is there a way to detect if my PC is "spied" upon with remote access?

Comment: Is this on Windows? When you say spy, do you mean using remote desktop/equivalent, a piece of software installed on your machine (like real vnc) or covertly? Are you trying to detect this programmatically?

Comment: Voting to migrate to SuperUser.com

Comment: this seems more like a question for superuser

Answer (score 1):

If you are running VNC server, the icon in the taskbar changes from white to black when someone connects to the machine remotely.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what is being used to "spy" on you. An administrator can shadow your session with remote desktop, though you would be able to see that they are logged in on the Users tab.  With some VNC clients there will be an indication, typically by a tray icon of some sort, but those can be hidden. Remote control solutions like LogMeIn and TeamViewer also usually have an indicator, but again, those can be bypassed. If you suspect someone may be remotely viewing your session, you can run a packet sniffer like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see if there are any packets on ports used by VNC or RDP (Remote Desktop runs on port 3389; the port for VNC will depend on how it's configured), or going to any site like logmein.com or teamviewer.com that might indicate someone using one of those sources.

Answer (score 1):

use TCP/IP view software to see what kind of ports your PC opened.
Try to install firewall software. on the firewall settings setup firewall ask whatever software try to communicate TCP/IP, UDP port.
default inspect 3389 port communications does not always help. You can setup any port for RDP in windows registry:)

Answer (score 0):

unless you are not running Terminal Services Server, if someone remote desktop to your machine, you will be prompted for confirmation, and if he gain access, you will be logged off.

you can find who's connected to your machine if you go to **Users** tab on the **Task Manager**